# Android use device flash as torch

Tags: java, android, android-camera

There is a need to use the built in device camera flash as a torch.
Unfortunately I don't have access to an Android device so I can only use the Android emulator.
How can I validate that my code does work?

I have been trying several times to update my app with different ways to access the camera flash and each time the app was crashed.

My app minimum OS version is 2.2,

At the moment I'm using the following code

```
private void turnFlashOn() {
        camera = Camera.open();
        Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    private void turnFlashOff() {
        camera = Camera.open();
        Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.stopPreview();
    }
```

Haven't tested it yet.

What is your way to use the camera flash?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd start by adding some debug code. Catch/display exceptions and the like. For example, if `Camera.open()` returns `null`, your code will generate a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Use this below link you will get better idea. [Refer this](http://code.google.com/p/torch/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/colinmcdonough/android/torch)

Comment: When your question is "why does this crash?" you should *always* post the stack trace! you are not describing anything about the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first two errors here is that you have called `Camera.open()` twice and never close it. You need to open it in `onResume()` and close it in `onPause()`, and in between operate on the `Camera` handle you obtained.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug on emulator and mock camera class (with jmockit) , but you will have to be careful -  not every camera on real devices supports torch mode ( or have a flash at all) - so you will have to check whether camera object supports this.

Once you got your code working correclty,  you will still have to test it on real device
( hint:  you can recruit testers  on android developers mailing lists if you ask politely and provide signed APK somewhere on the web so people can install it )